# copyto google apps script without "copy" in sheet name

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use **copyTo** to duplicate an entire sheet from one Google Sheet to a brand new one. Everything works great however, the newly created Sheets all say "Copy" and then the Sheet name. Is there a way to remove the word Copy? Code is below.

```
function setupSheet() 
{
var sources = SpreadsheetApp.openById('172teYmA4Bz61PscMQiTmpqWdvBUBDu_J2hR0m_8i_b8');
var allSheets = ['Display Case', 'Your Badges', 'Badge Directory', 'Activate Sheet'];

 allSheets.forEach(function(each) 
 {
  var thisSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sourcevalues = sources.getSheetByName(each).copyTo(thisSheet)
 });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var sourcevalues = 
sources.getSheetByName(each).copyTo(thisSheet).setName(each);
```

Comment: How do I set the names? If I leave nothing, then it tries to rename everything to Untitled spreadsheet. If I try to use getName(each) I get a Cannot find method getName(string).

Comment: Sorry there is my fault. `each` instead `getName()`